# Google Maps API v2: Prevent scrolling over the map border

Tags: android, google-maps

with my standard setup of Google Map API v2 it seems to be allowed to scroll outside the existing map data. There is actually a limit for scrolling, but it seems to be quite a bit outside the actual map bounds.

Is there an easy way of fixing this?

[image]

Comment: Any update on this, especially when called from the JS API?

Comment: I have long moved onto other projects. I don't think I found a nice solution to the problem, but check out AndyHs solution, this might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I use function which is called from onCameraChange. It moves the camera back to inside the allowed area of the map.

```
// First set the bounds
private static final LatLng NORTHEAST = new LatLng("LAT HERE", "LNG HERE");
private static final LatLng SOUTHWEST = new LatLng("LAT HERE", "LNG HERE");
private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS = new LatLngBounds(SOUTHWEST, NORTHEAST);
```

The method looks like this:

```
 if (BOUNDS.contains(googleMap.getCameraPosition().target)) {
  return;
}

double x = googleMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude;
double y = googleMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;

double maxX = BOUNDS.northeast.longitude;
double maxY = BOUNDS.northeast.latitude;
double minX = BOUNDS.southwest.longitude;
double minY = BOUNDS.southwest.latitude;

if (x < minX) {
  x = minX;
}
if (x > maxX) {
  x = maxX;
}
if (y < minY) {
  y = minY;
}
if (y > maxY) {
  y = maxY;
}


googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(y, x)));
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is a solution, true. It looks even better if you animate to the new camera position. It is not really a solution to the problem though, because you can still scroll over the border of the defined bounds. What I would like to have would be the same behaviour as in the Google Maps App: You can't scroll further.